# displaying number of students doing each course

Tags: c++

In an earlier question I was given the advice to use a class for storing student information. My issue now is: when I display students once and then try entering more students without exiting the program, it does not display the newly-added students.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class students {
public:
    char name[50];
    char sname[45];

    int idno;
    char cours[40];
    int age;
    int modules;

    void read_data();
    void display();
};

void students::read_data()
{
    cout << "Enter name :";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter Surname : ";
    cin >> sname;
    cout << "Enter course : ";
    cin >> cours;
    cout << "Enter age :";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Enter modules:";
    cin >> modules;
}
void students::display()
{
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Student ID no : " << idno << endl;
    cout << "Student name is :" << name << endl;
    cout << "Student Surname is : " << sname << endl;
    cout << "Student course is :" << cours << endl;
    cout << "Student age is  :" << age << endl;
    cout << "Student modules are:" << modules << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream cfile;
    ofstream sfile;
    char dow;
    int arr = 0;
    do {

        students stud[100];

        cout << "Press 1 Enter record \n";
        cout << "Press 2 To check student course file \n";
        cout << "\n\t Select option::";

        int idcheck = 0;

        int sw;
        cin >> sw;

        switch (sw) {

        case 1:

            cout << "\n Enter the data of the student no " << arr + 1 << " is :\n";

            cout << "\t Enter the Roll No = ";
            int id2;
            int id;

            cin >> id;

            for (int j = 0; j <= arr; j++) {

                id2 = id;
                if (id2 == stud[j].idno) {
                    idcheck = 1;
                }
            }
            if (idcheck != 1) {
                stud[arr].idno = id;

                stud[arr].read_data();

                arr = arr + 1;
            }
            else {
                cout << "This Record is Already Entered \n";
            }

            break;
        case 2: {
            string str;
            int n, count = 0;

            cout << "Enter number of courses: ";
            cin >> n;

            for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {

                cout << "Enter course: ";
                cin >> str;

                count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i <= str.size(); i++)

                {

                    if (str == stud[i].cours)

                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                cout << "Number of students doing " << str << " are " << count << endl;
            }
        }
            cout << "\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                cout << setw(12) << "Rollno ||";
                cout << setw(12) << " Name   ||";
                cout << setw(12) << " Surname    || ";
                cout << setw(12) << "Age  ||";
                cout << setw(12) << " Course  ||";
                cout << setw(12) << " Module   ||";
                for (int k = 0; k < arr; k++) {
                    if (stud[k].idno != 'd') {
                        cout << "\n";
                        cout << " ";
                        cout << setw(5) << stud[k].idno;

                        cout << setw(15) << stud[k].name;

                        cout << setw(14) << stud[k].sname;

                        cout << setw(14) << stud[k].age;

                        cout << setw(12) << stud[k].cours;

                        cout << setw(14) << stud[k].modules;
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "\n______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

            break;

            break;

        default:
            cout << "\t Wrong option Selected ";
            break;
        }

        cout << "\n\n\t Do You Want to Continue Again [Y/N]";
        cin >> dow;

    } while (dow == 'y');
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `for(int j=0; j<=arr; j++)` looks like an off by 1 error.

Comment: i'm trying to display the number of students doing each course. it does that fine. but when i try entering more students it does not display the other students i added on the second attempt.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {` Why?

Comment: what do you mean by "looks like an off by 1 error." @drescherjm

Comment: If you google that term there will be many hits. `for(int j=0; j<=arr; j++)` should be `for(int j=0; j<arr; j++)` because in `for(int j=0; j<=arr; j++)` you are looking at 1 extra student.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, letting you inspect the values of all variables as they change as each line in your program executes, and observe your program's logical execution flow, what observations did you make? This is what a debugger is for. If you haven't yet learned how to use a debugger, now is your opportunity to learn how to use it in order to find and fix your own bugs, which sounds much more efficient than posting a question on stackoverflow and hoping that someone else will figure it out for you.

Comment: to answer your why it is to increment the amount of times i can enter courses if i enter two courses it will allow me to enter two courses only

Comment: i am using Dev++ to code my program idk if there's a setting to debug line by line@SamVarshavchik

Comment: The following link seems to explain how to use Dev C++ http://eilat.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/cis1_5/HowToDebug.htm

Comment: let me try change the code @drescherjm

Comment: I don't think that will fix the problem but it is a different issue.

Comment: let me try debug the program @drescherjm

Comment: You really should only post formatted code. Last time you didn't do it. This time someone else did it for you. It's much easier to read formatted code. If your IDE doesn't do it for you you can use http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: @ThomasSablik i thought i did fromat it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: ***i thought i did fromat it*** I fixed the formatting using http://format.krzaq.cc

Comment: @Toby Speight i tried to reduce it as much as i could so anyone who wanted to test it could do so.

Comment: that site isn't a trusted site, so my computer would not allow it. @drescherjm

Comment: I understand, at work its blocked for me as well. If I need to use it I have to enter the IP address instead. Thankfully when I get  a blocked message the block actually reveals the ipaddress..

Comment: You should be able to reduce the code much further - you shouldn't need to read any input, for a start.

Comment: oh so only relevant code to elaborate the action should be sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {

    cout << "Enter course: ";
    cin >> str;

    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= str.size(); i++) //maybe should be i<=arr;
    {
        if (str == stud[i].cours)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of students doing " << str << " are " << count << endl;
}
```

I think the problem is the for loop with i<=str.size();
I think the correct way to show all the students of that course is: i<=arr.

Comment: wow thanks @FouLiNuX, i thought getting the size would find my solution yet it was supposed to check the array

Comment: `str.size()` is the number of characters in the course name not the number of students.

Comment: ok. so arr gets the number of students

Comment: That whole loop looks like a long-winded way to write a simple `std::count_if()` call.

Comment: that must be another way to implement what i failed to do. idk how to implement the std::count_if() call, i'd have to learn